# I am trying to convert String into integer in Kotlin. Positive numbers are working fine, but negative number is creating issue

Tags: kotlin

So I am trying to solve Reverse Polish notation question. I wanted to try out in Kotlin language. I am able to solve this in Java but in Kotlin it is not allowing "-11" to push onto stack.
---code----

```
import java.util.*

fun reversePolish(tokens: Array<String>):Int{
    var st = Stack<Int>()

    for (token in tokens){
        if(token.all { Character.isDigit(it) }) {
            st.push(token.toIntOrNull())
        }
        else{
            var n2 = st.pop()
            var n1 = st.pop()
            when(token){
                "+" -> st.push(n1 + n2)
                "-" -> st.push(n1 - n2)
                "*" -> st.push(n1 * n2)
                "/" -> st.push(n1/n2)
            }
        }
    }

    return st.pop()
}

fun main() {
    var arr = arrayOf("10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+")
    print(reversePolish(arr))
}
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Follow through what happens in the loop when `token` gets set to `"-11"`…

Comment: @gidds Sorry, I didn't get you...Can you elaborate?

Comment: You pass a list of strings into your function; it will loop through them, setting `token` to each string in turn.  When it gets to `"-11"`, what will happen next?  What will `token.all{ Character.isDigit(it) }` return, and will it take the `if` branch or the `else` branch?  And so on…  Once you work out what your program is actually doing, you should be able to see how that differs from what you want it to do.

Comment: @gidds: Thanks for the input..I did what you said..So the issue is when -11 string gets in the loop, it get stuck at the Character.isDigit(it) and does not allow other strings to get in...so next iteration is jumping to else condition and that's why I am getting exception.

Comment: Gets ‘stuck’?  I doubt it.  Try running it in a debugger, step through the lines, and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try this

```
fun reversePolish(tokens: Array<String>): Int {
    val stack = Stack<Int>()
    tokens.forEach { item ->
        when (item.toIntOrNull()) {
            null -> {
                val secondNumber = stack.pop()
                val firstNumber = stack.pop()
                when (item) {
                    "+" -> stack.push(firstNumber + secondNumber)
                    "-" -> stack.push(firstNumber - secondNumber)
                    "*" -> stack.push(firstNumber * secondNumber)
                    "/" -> stack.push(firstNumber / secondNumber)
                }
            }
            else -> {
                stack.push(item.toInt())
            }
        }
        
    }
    return stack.pop()
}
```